# Include file in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    include($_GET['page'] . ".php");
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

It's simple code to include php files 
i want to include all files with all extention like txt & gif & and file without extention for exemple file called lab which contain a simple password

here how i include all php files 
page.php?page=php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource=[name file without extention]

i have tried with null byte %00 to include lab file but not work :/
any suggestion ?

Comment: Great, finally I can include everything I want and get the server config of strangers without violating the law!

Comment: include doesn't accept wildcards. you'll have to `glob()` and loop on the results. and note that this kind of structure is incredibly insecure/dangerous. You're allow users to specify ANY php file for which they know the path for - that means they can directly influence what is being executed on the server. So... by all means, deploy this code, and enjoy the holes in your foot when your users pull the triggers you weren't expecting to be pulled.

Comment: Seriously, I'm not sure what you try to do. Why would you want to do that? There is really no need to include *everything*, without checking it's validity.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for `include` or just unaware of [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)? include() is for executing PHP code, if you're trying to get .txt and .gif files for display, you can probably use fopen for txt, and something like `readfile` for images.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $filename="file"
    $dirpath="dir";
    $dir_files=scandir($dirpath);
    for($i=2;$i<count($dir_files);$i++) {
       if(strpos($dir_files[$i],$filename) === 0 && $dir_files[$i] != $filename) {
           echo $dir_files[$i];
       }
    }
?>
```

This piece of code will loop through all files in a directory and check if the name of the file starts with the filename that you are looking for. The second comparison is to check if the is a directory or not. The for loop starts from 2 because the first two elements are always . and ..

Comment: The second comparison isn't checking if the is a directory. It's checking if it's **not equal** to `$filename`.

Comment: Yes, i think thats not a problem, since he is looking for a file by its name without the extension.

Comment: Practically it's the same as the first comparison, but it will prevent the echo/include if the extension is passed too.

Comment: No, the second comparison is there to avoid printing directory's with the filename.

Comment: What do you mean by no? It may avoid printing directories with the filename, but also prevent printing the file if the filename with the extension is given.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but on his example he is not using the full name of the file, just the name without the extension.